# Ubuntu preseed file: setting up multiple user accounts?

Tags: ubuntu, users, preseed

As mentioned in this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs04.html, it is possible to create a "...password for **a** first regular user's account" during an unattended installation with a preseed file.
So am I correct in reading "a first regular users' account" as "ONLY one regular's user" as opposed to "this one, and many more"?
And if it were possible to create more than one other user beside root, how would I go unto this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preseed/late_command` to run the necessary commands.  A very simple (untested) example line in the preseed file

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target useradd seconduser
```